# Javascript match() regex to detect URLs and link to embedded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a small plugin that takes the href value of hyperlinks to pages on YouTube, Vimeo, DailyMotion and KickStarter and then convert it to the embeded URL to display in an iframe within a lightbox.

Of course, the reason why I'm here is I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work properly! These are the possible links that it can accept:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[token]
http://www.youtu.be/[token]
http://www.vimeo.com/[token]
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/[token]
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/[token]/[token]
```

And these are the embed links to use for the iframe:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/[token]
http://player.vimeo.com/video/[token]
https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/[token]
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/[token]/[token]/widget/video.html
```

Here is the code I've got so far

```
if (videoURL = href.match(/(youtube|youtu|vimeo|dailymotion|kickstarter)\.(com|be)\/(watch\?v=([\w-]+)|([\w-]+)|video|projects)\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-]+)/)) {

    var src = '';

    if (videoURL[1] == 'youtube')
        src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoURL[4];

    if (videoURL[1] == 'youtu')
        src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoURL[3];

    if (videoURL[1] == 'vimeo')
        src = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoURL[3];

    if (videoURL[1] == 'dailymotion')
        src = 'https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/' + videoURL[6];

    if (videoURL[1] == 'kickstarter')
        src = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/' + videoURL[6] + '/' + videoURL[7] + '/widget/video.html';

    if (src) {
        var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
            src: src,
            frameborder: 0,
            vspace: 0,
            hspace: 0,
            scrolling: 'no',
            allowfullscreen: ''
        });

        $container.append(iframe);
    }

    iframe.load(function() {
        $loader.remove();
    });
} else {
    $this.liteboxError();
    $loader.remove();
}
```

But currently, only KickStarter videos are working, the rest just return the liteboxError. However if I remove the KickStarter part of the regex, like this:

```
videoURL = href.match(/(youtube|youtu|vimeo|dailymotion)\.(com|be)\/(watch\?v=([\w-]+)|([\w-]+)|video|)\/([\w-]+)/)
```

Then it's only the DailyMotion videos working, and again if I remove the DailyMotion regex, like this:

```
videoURL = href.match(/(youtube|youtu|vimeo)\.(com|be)\/(watch\?v=([\w-]+)|([\w-]+))/)
```

Then the YouTube and Vimeo videos work fine.

Was just hoping someone could shine some light as to what's wrong with the regex I'm using?

Comment: **HINT**: The part after `projects` in `projects)\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-]+)` is no present for youtube and vimeo links

Comment: I did think that, but I assumed the array would just produce an 'undefined' value?

Comment: Not when you use a `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of hjpotter92, I managed to get this code working for my regex:

```
if (videoURL = href.match(/(youtube|youtu|vimeo|dailymotion|kickstarter)\.(com|be)\/((watch\?v=([-\w]+))|(video\/([-\w]+))|(projects\/([-\w]+)\/([-\w]+))|([-\w]+))/)) { }
```

Then obviously changing the group numbers accordingly when using `videoURL[*]` to insert the data to the `src` variable!

Answer (score 3):

Since the URLs have completely different types of nests for giving you the token to actual video, I think you'd need to nest them one inside the other:

```
(youtu\.be|((youtube|vimeo|dailymotion|kickstarter)\.com))/(watch\?v=([-\w]+)|video/([-\w]+)|projects/([-\w]+)|([-\w]+))
```

> [image: Regular expression visualization]

You can see and test some cases [here](http://regexr.com/v1?38kuc)

Comment: For some reason it was still throwing back an error! But your answer (along with the link to regexr, which I'd not even heard of) helped me in a lot of ways. I'm just about to post my answer with what worked for me, thank you for your help! It's really appreciated!